# Not obtaining desired output C++

Tags: c++, cin

I am working on a triplet code actually. The problem statement goes as follow:
The task is to find their comparison points by comparing a[0] with b[0], a[1] with b[1], and a[2] with b[2].

`If a[i] > b[i]`, then Alice is awarded 1 point.
`If a[i] < b[i]`, then Bob is awarded 1 point.
`If a[i] = b[i]`, then neither person receives a point.
Comparison points is the total points a person earned.
The result has to be a two valued array.
The code appears correct and fine to me, but iam not getting the desired and correct output.
Somebody please help.
The code i wrote is as follow:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a[3];
    int b[3];
    int r[2] = {r[0],r[1]};
    r[0]=0;
    r[1]=0;
    cin>>a[3]>>b[3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            if(a[i] >b[i]){
                r[0]=r[0]+1;
            }else if(b[i]>a[i]){
                r[1] = r[1]+1;

            }else{
                r[0]=r[0]+0;
                r[1]=r[1]+0;
            }
        }
    cout<<r[0]<<" "<<r[1];
}
```

Comment: What do you expect this to mean? `int r[2] = {r[0],r[1]};`

Comment: `cin>>a[3]>>b[3];` is outside the bounds of the array. It has indices 0 to 2. You need a loop if you're going to read multiple values like the `for` loop you have below that. You don't actually need any arrays for this at all. Read 2 values, compare, score, repeat.

Comment: Please also read [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Comment: `a[3]` does not mean "the entire array `a`". If it existed, it would be a single `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of this question is easy. First You need to take array value using loop. Then compare them.
http://cpp.sh/3kk5f

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[3],b[3],r[2]={};

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) cin>>a[i];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) cin>>b[i];
    
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
     if(a[i] > b[i])   r[0]++;
     else if(b[i]>a[i]) r[1]++;
    }
    
    cout<<r[0]<<" "<<r[1]<<endl;
  
}
```

input:

```
1 2 3
1 4 5
```

output:

```
0 2
```

Comment: Note: `int a[3],b[3],r[2]; r[0] = r[1] = 0;` is equivalent to `int a[3],b[3],r[2] = {};`